# What is the best way to have a user enter a time in Flask WT Forms?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I want the user to select a military time within a Flask Form. So far I have a list of hours and a list of minutes. I also use SqlAlchemy and want the data saved into a DateTime column.

```
hours = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13",
            "14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23"]
minutes = ["00","05","10","15","20","25","30","35","40","45","50","55"]

time_hours = SelectField('Hours', choices=hours)
time_minutes = SelectField('Minutes', choices=minutes)
```

I could use two separate SelectFields, one for hours and the other for minutes, and combine them within the view, finally saving them into a DateTime field. That will complicate things when I set up an edit page and try to fill in the form's data with the data stored in the database. Does anyone know if there is a "proper" way to select a time within Flask `WT Forms`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install the package [`WTForms-Components`](https://wtforms-components.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#timefield) and use `TimeField`  as follows:

```
from wtforms_components import TimeField

class YourForm(FlaskForm):
    ...
    time = TimeField('Time')
```

It will render something like this

[image]

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf Thanks for the answer. I do have a related question and was wondering if you would be willing to take a look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74248496/how-to-make-the-time-field-dropdown-in-flask-wt-form-datetimelocalfield